# Why isn't my view re-rendered again as expected?

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, sapui5

I created a custom control which includes a currentValue property. I defined it in metadata as below:

```
properties: 
{
    currentValue: 
    {
        type: 'int',
        defaultValue: 0
    },...
```

in my Main.controller.js I'm calling the custom control that I created and changed it's currentValue property as below.

```
var oCustomControl = this.getView().byId("customID1");
oCustomControl.setCurrentValue(75);
```

in this step in my control.js, I didn't create a setCurrentValue function. Because I know UI5 is creating it itself. But the currentValue property of my control couldn't been updated. So I'm thinking my control couldn't been rerendered. So I overwrote the currentValue setter and change it as below:

```
setCurrentValue : function(iCurrentValue)
{
    this.setProperty("currentValue", iCurrentValue);
},
```

But still I couldn't see the value which I changed in my view.

Here is my renderer:

```
renderer : 
{

    render : function(oRm, oControl) {



        var layout = oControl.createGauges();//I created layout

        oRm.write("<div");
        oRm.writeControlData(layout);
        oRm.writeClasses(); 
        oRm.write(">");
        oRm.renderControl(layout);
        oRm.addClass('verticalAlignment');
        oRm.write("</div>");
    }
},
```

I am thinking now maybe it is because I'm rendering layout as a control?

and my other properties are related with [d3.js](https://github.com/thlorenz/d3-gauge). And I coded d3.js codes in my onAfterRendering function.

Comment: can you post whole new custom controller?

Comment: I added my renderer function and updated my question for you. my other codes are for d3.js which I shared the link at below in my question

Comment: @melong: Are you inheriting some control? or writing from scratch?

Comment: No I am not inheriting any control except sap.ui.core.Control :) I tried to write my own control according to these d3 codes

Comment: what exactly you want with this new control.. I am not sure what's is the requirement of this. I can help in creating one with that requirement

Comment: our customers wants this gauge in our project. So I have to create a custom control for gauge in ui5. It would be very nice if I could set values of my properties from controller. In this case I only can assign values of my properties when I create the control in my view. I can't set any properties in my controller. I can invalidate my view and can set the properties of my control. But actually this is not what I want :)

Comment: and for now I'm just trying to do a standart gauge like in this link https://github.com/thlorenz/d3-gauge/blob/master/d3-gauge.js

Comment: oRm.renderControl(layout); //this can be the culprit.. sap expects sap control as per my understanding.. I am not quite sure.

Comment: yes oRm.writeControlData(oControl); with this code it is working now :)) thank you @Sunil B

Comment: @melong can you add that as answer to help others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99783/discussion-between-melomg-and-sunil-b-n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by changing

`oRm.writeControlData(layout);` this line as follow:

oRm.writeControlData(oControl);

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code looks fine.
Accept that you have specified:

```
bindable: 'bindable'
```

What should that do?
And what does `rerender()`?

The method to render a control is called `renderer()`.

But you don't need to call it when you say:

```
this.setProperty("currentValue", iCurrentValue);
```

If you dont say true it will rerender the control.

It would be nice to know whats inside your `renderer()` function, or what happens when you call `getCurrentValue()`.

Comment: I saw bindable when I create my custom control from a source. :) and I thougth it is useful for binding items like bindItems methods. But I have no idea about it. I will search it later. I deleted it now and in my setCurrentValue function I also deleted rerender function and updated. I used rerender method because I was trying to render the custom control again and it was the only function to render :) but still it isn't rendered